# Select query didn't return right value

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this

```
create table Bids (
b_id INT not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
u_id integer not null,
foreign key (u_id) references Users(u_id),
i_id integer not null,
foreign key (i_id) references Items(i_id),
bid_amount long,
}
```

then I run the query

```
Select * from Bids Where bid_amount in ( Select MAX(bid_amount) from Bids) 
and i_id=1
```

the return value is 950 like in the picture
[image: slect max bidamout]

but it is not the right value when I select all, it supposes to be 1050 like the picture below

[image]

what happened with my query ?

Comment: so what should i do if i want the query to return the 1050 value ?, change the type to integer ?

Comment: 'to facilitate the use of code written for SQL implementations from other vendors, MySQL maps data types' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html in your case the mysql mapping is to mediumtext.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `bid_amount` as text which is not a good practice, I suggest you to alter your structure and assign proper type integer/double. For now you need to cast your column as number and then you can get proper result.

A quick hack not a solution would be

```
Select * from Bids 
Where bid_amount in ( Select MAX(bid_amount + 0) from Bids) 
and i_id=1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f75/2)

```
Select * from Bids 
Where bid_amount in ( Select MAX(CAST(bid_amount as DECIMAL(9,2))) from Bids) 
and i_id=1
```

Or

```
Select * from Bids 
Where bid_amount in ( Select MAX(CONVERT(bid_amount ,UNSIGNED INTEGER) ) from Bids) 
and i_id=1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f75/6)

Comment: thank you it works, but I wonder why using Long type mean storing as a text?

Comment: @NguyễnEric As per your provided sample data it will give you 1050 as max value http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f75/6. For 1100  can you create a fiddle with relevant data set ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select * from Bids where bid_amount = ( select MAX(bid_amount) from Bids) 
and i_id=1
```

Comment: it is still return 950